# Many pipelines and buffers need to display one at the time,

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have more than 1000 individual pipeline in one shapefile with 4 different buffer size. I wish to show one pipeline at a time with its corresponding buffers after each other in a very quick way. I tried to query out every single line after each other front of all the people during the screening meeting but it is way to long and painful process with over 1000 lines. I was thinking to split them and calculate the buffers for each line but again that would take too much time. 
I am trying to see if a building fell into one of my buffer but if all the pipeline is displayed the map is way to crowd and the buffers (I'm using only the line without fill) are overlaying unable to see which one is belongs to the particular line I am looking fat. I need to switch fairly quick the lines so the others can decide if the line is close to a house or not.
[image: All the pipelines and buffers![][1![enter image description here]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPj4x.jpg)

Comment: You're doing this visually, meaning you don't have points for houses but you just have the buffer line and are visually looking for something in the image within that outline? If so, there's no fast way to do this without a custom tool or script (which basically makes use of a definition query as the current answer states). You're looking for a 'step through and only show selected' tool, and there isn't one built in to Arc. There are some other questions here on the subject though.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. There *might* be a way to do it using Data Driven Pages with your pipelines as the index layer and a [Page Definition Query](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000004000000) on the buffers. But I don't know the exact steps or if it would work, and I don't have time to test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just create all four buffers, with different radius, for the entire shapefile. Then use a definition query for each 5 layers (1 pipeline + 4 pipeline buffer) with the objectid of the pipeline you are interested.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes I already did this but I have 9 hours to go through more than 1000 pipeline to see if a house fell inside of one of the buffer. Query out that many pipeline each by each will take more than 8 hours. I am looking for a solution which will help me to show each line after each other quickly.

Comment: Then you should change your question to reflect the problem, not a way to implement a very inefficient solution.  Theme-on-theme query would solve the actual problem in seconds.

Comment: @VandaJ As Vince says... why are you checking them one at a time instead of all at once? What exactly are you trying to check/do?

Comment: I am sorry that I am not a perfect question composer but I appreciate your kind help. I am trying to see if one particular pipeline 300ppm buffer area contains any house, church etc. To see all the pipelines with all the buffers get way to crowd and we can not identify building on the Imagery base map. If I am still not clear I apologies, please ask back if it is still not clear so I can help you to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: @VandaJ Please use the **edit** button to improve your question by providing any necessary clarifications.  [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) is well worth reviewing.